# Android App Manifest Setup

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am fairly new to Android App Development and was looking at some example code here.  I understand that the manifest xml here states that by pressing the app to launch the map but I wanted to implement a login as well.  I was wondering if anyone here had any advice in terms of how popular apps format this?  Do they have a login as their launcher or the application itself?  Thank You!

```
<activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you look to change the launcher activity

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="@string/title" > 

<intent-filter> 

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

</intent-filter> 

</activity>
```

You can put the login activity that way

Comment: And fire a intent when he logins ,to get him to mainacitivty